# Is it normal for devices to change their device numbers?

Tags: mount, mountpoint

Last time I booted, my OS drive was sdc1 and my Data drive was sda1.  Now they are reversed.  Are they assigned randomly at boot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is normal. Usually it happens because devices get detected in a different order. They share the /dev/sd* device names, and they will change according to what you have plugged in at the time.

You can work around it in two ways:

1. Label the partitions then mount them by label
2. Mount them by UUID

Labelling a disk can be done with (for example)

```
tune2fs -L MyLabel /dev/sdxx
```

then use `LABEL=Mylabel` as the device name in `/etc/fstab`

Mounting can also be done by using `UUID=` in `/etc/fstab`

The UUID can be obtained by `blkid`, then you can put in /etc/fstab UUID=xxxxxxxxxx as device name. UUID is unique.