# Permanently mount HDD

Tags: mount, hard-drive, fstab

What I'm trying to do is permanently mount an HDD on my RPI. I found that you can do this by executing `df` and add the partition found here to `/etc/fstab`. My `fstab` file looks like this:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot        vfat      defaults,noatime,noauto,x-systemd.automount    0   0
# rootfs is not mounted in fstab as we do it via initramfs. Uncomment for remount (slower boot)
#/dev/mmcblk0p2  /           ext4      defaults,noatime    0   0
/dev/sda5        /media/HDD  auto      defaults,noatime    0   0
```

But after returning to the RPI after a while, I performed the `df` command and got following output:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs          377792         0    377792   0% /dev
tmpfs             382912     38796    344116  11% /run
/dev/mmcblk0p2  14982536   6299204   7899204  45% /
tmpfs             382912         0    382912   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs             382912         0    382912   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1    244988     32458    212531  14% /boot
/dev/sdb1        1023996    310612    713384  31% /media/WINRE_DRV
/dev/sdb2         262144     34060    228084  13% /media/SYSTEM_DRV
/dev/sdb3        1019904    513568    506336  51% /media/LRS_ESP
/dev/sdb6       26214396  24587852   1626544  94% /media/LENOVO
/dev/sdb5      932056060 526612012 405444048  57% /media/Windows8_OS_
/dev/sdb7       16045052  11980696   4064356  75% /media/PBR_DRV
tmpfs              76584         0     76584   0% /run/user/1000
```

To one I want to mount is `/media/Windows8_OS_`, but this one changed from `/dev/sda5` to `/dev/sdb5` over time apparently. Does anyone have an idea how I can permanently mount this partition?

What I should mention is that the HDD is an internal HDD in a case from a previous laptop I owned. I don't know if this may cause the problem I'm having?

Comment: Related (and offers some solutions - using the disk label or UUID): [Is it normal for devices to change their device numbers?](https://askubuntu.com/a/708552/178692)

Comment: Ok so using the label in `/etc/fstab` seeemed to work, thanks @steeldriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So using a `LABEL=` in `/etc/fstab` seemed to solve the problem. Silly question in hindsight, but I'll leave it here for people searching for the problem.

Perform `blkid` and put `LABEL={label}` or `UUID={uuid}` in `/etc/fstab` as per [Is it normal for devices to change their device numbers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708548/is-it-normal-for-devices-to-change-their-device-numbers/708552#708552)'s answer by @LilloX